# Can a dwarf have a coffin AND a memorial?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

Alright - so I've got a dwarf that I thought was awesome who has died. I want to build a nice memorial to him, but he liked coffins (he really did. he even engraved one in the floor =P) and I'd like to stick him in one of those as well. Is that possible? Or will a dwarf who's been memorialized be skipped over for a coffin?

In similar veins, is it possible to memorialize a dwarf after they are already in a coffin? And can a dwarf who's had a tomb prepared while they were living be given a memorial to put inside their tomb?

Comment: I you can coffin them and memorialise them. Not 100% sure.

Comment: *he liked coffins (he really did. he even engraved one in the floor =P)* One of the many reasons this game is both weird and awesome.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After some messing around I've determined that dwarfs *can* get both treatments and it doesn't matter the order in which they are done. Dwarfs who are already interred in my catacombs have their names available when engraving slabs as memorials, and dwarfs who I gave memorials to have since been buried as their remains have been found.

Additionally, Dwarfs who have memorials are still listed as options in the Engrave Memorial Slab menu, which also lists whether or not the dwarf has any existing memorials. I assume that this means I can engrave multiple memorials to the same dwarf, though I haven't tried it.

Comment: Yes, you can have as many memorials as you like for a single Dwarf (or any other creature which you can make a memorial for).